# StackMaps - Interactive Maps of Stack Exchange Communities

Tags: app, users

[image: StackMaps Logo]

## [StackMaps](https://johndbritton.com/stackmaps) - Interactive Maps of Stack Exchange Communities

https://johndbritton.com/stackmaps

### What

Easily view users from your favorite Stack Exchange community on a map.

### Why

I wanted to make it easy to browse the [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com) users by location, so I built this little hack as part of my [48HourApps](https://48hourapps.com) series. It works for all Stack Exchange sites.

### Who

Created by [John Britton](https://johndbritton.com)

Logo built to order by [Chris Kennedy](http://kennedysgarage.com). Marker "[spiderfying](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)" by [George MacKerron](http://mackerron.com/home/). Searchable dropdown using [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.com/chosen) by [Harvest](https://www.getharvest.com/). Google Maps, jQuery, and GitHub were used too.

Comment: Is this by location specified in the profile? How do you get the exact location then?

Comment: Yes, the location is based on the profile. I use a geocoding library to place the pins.

Comment: When accessing I received the following errors: http://i.imgur.com/PiAJNg6.png

Comment: Thanks for the note. This is probably a result of Yahoo changing their geocoding API. Pull Requests welcome: http://github.com/johndbritton/stackmaps

Comment: It's working again, I moved it to the Google geocoder.

Comment: Can you clarify in which order the users are plotted as one clicks the `show more users` button?

Comment: I think it's based on most active, but it's been so long I don't remember.

Comment: Hi @John, if you have a moment, could you update your application to use the new version of Google Maps API released last summer? Right now, it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: I now get a popover that says, "This page can't load Google Maps correctly." and numerous errors and warnings in the browser console. ... Also, loading the app/site via HTTPS results in additional failures due to "Mixed Content".